# how to decide if bind() need parenthesis in the parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, bind

I am using bind() to bind a function and its parameters together. I used the build-in functor multiplies and I also tried a function I wrote myself AddVal2(). The following is a correct version of the code. But I really don't understand why `std::bind(std::multiplies<int>(),std::placeholders::_1,10)` has to include `()` with `multiplies<int>`, while `bind(AddVal2,std::placeholders::_1,10)` write `AddVal2` instead of `AddVal2()`. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
void AddVal2(int x, int y)
{ std::cout << x+y << std::endl;}

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
        std::vector<int> vec_result;
        std::transform(vec.begin(),vec.begin()+2,std::back_inserter(vec_result),std::bind(std::multiplies<int>(),std::placeholders::_1,10));
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator itr = vec_result.begin(); itr !=vec_result.end();++itr){std::cout << *itr << std::endl;}
        for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::bind(AddVal2,std::placeholders::_1,10));
}
```

Comment: Look at what the first parameter for [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is then look at what you're [passing it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies).

Comment: `std::multiplies<int>` is a *type*, `AddVal2` is a *value*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple: `std::multiplies<T>` is a class template which defines a 
function call operator. It looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct multiplies {
    // some typedefs are here, too
    T operator()(T const& a0, T const& a1) const { return a0 * a1; }
};
```

To create such an object, you'll use a default constructor, i.e., `std::multiplies<T>()`.

On the other hand `AddVal2` is a function. To get a function object from a normal function you just mention the function and it'll decay into a function pointer. Alternatively you can also use `&AddVal2` to explicitly obtain a function pointer (for member functions you *have* to explicitly take the address).

Comment: Thank you! So as you mentioned in the end, for a member function func() of class A  I need to write &(A::func) to get the function pointer?

Comment: @daydayup: You can use `&(A::func)` but `&A::func` will do. Of course, if `A::func` is overloaded things get a bit more tricky: you'd need to select the appropriate signature, e.g., using a cast (the same applies to functions).

Comment: Hmmm I am still confused a little bit.  I feel like std::multiplies<T>() represents the operator () function but not the constructor.

Comment: @daydayup: nope - you can create a temporary object without a function call operator the same way, e.g., `int()` or `std::string()`. Also you can avoid the parenthesis using a named object: `std::multiplies<int> m; ... std::bind(m, _1, 10) ...`

Comment: @daydayup - Applying `()` to the name of a _type_ means that you're invoking a constructor. Applying `()` to a _variable_ means you're invoking an `operator()` (unless the variable is a function pointer, in which case you're invoking whatever function it points to). If you wrote `std::multiplies<T>()(a,b)`, you'd be invoking first the constructor, then the `operator()`. But you certainly don't want to do this in `std::bind`.